# ClusterSingletonManager not failing over

Tags: java, akka, akka-cluster

I have been testing a Master / Worker cluster with the following set up:

- 2 virtual servers, each server has a Master and a Worker (separate jvms)
- Master is instantiated with ClusterSingletonManager
- The Masters are also the seed nodes.

I was testing the fail over of the Masters by manually shutting down the "Active" Master node. In the scenario where the Workers are not processing tasks the fail over works fine. The "Non-active" Master node does detect the other node as unreachable and eventually will start it's Master actor.

But if the workers are busy then fail over does not completely work. The "Non-active" Master node does detect the other as unreachable and quarantines as indicated in the below message but the node never starts the Master actor.

> 2014-07-23 23:52:31,777  INFO [JobRunner-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17] Quarantined address [akka.tcp://JobRunner@12.3.201.135:40000] is still unreachable or has not been restarted. Keeping it quarantined.

Anybody have any ideas why this is happening and if there is solution to this?

Thanks.
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

In the end putting the Master nodes on to their own servers (separate from the Workers) worked.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Akka are you using? There has been improvements in heartbeat priotization recently – please upgrade to `2.3.4` and check.

Comment: I'm using 2.3.2, will give 2.3.4 a try. Thanks.

Comment: Update, before the switch to 2.3.4 the fail over sort of worked. I left it running overnight, shut down the workers, and after about 17 hours the node decided to start the Master actor. 

The switch to version 2.3.4 (Scala 2.10) didn't solve the problem. Detection of unreachable still works and so does the quarantine but for some reason it just won't start up the Master when the workers are busy processing. Does the worker and server have to be on different servers?

Comment: No, they don't have to be on different physical servers. They could be the same jvm for what it's worth actually - but listening on different ports. Have you seen this: [hseeberger/akkamazing](https://github.com/hseeberger/akkamazing) and this sample apps: [akka-sample-cluster-scala](https://typesafe.com/activator/template/akka-sample-cluster-scala) esp. this sample: [StatsSampleOneMaster.scala](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-samples/akka-sample-cluster-scala/src/main/scala/sample/cluster/stats/StatsSampleOneMaster.scala). This could help you spot some difference perhaps?

Comment: Without seeing code it is very hard to debug this issue. I think the akka-user mailing list is a much better place to discuss these style of questions that might need long code or log snippets.

Comment: thanks for the input guys. when I have more time to dig around this issue I'll post it up in the akka-user mailing list.